# Change background image with Time

Tags: macos, graphics, settings

I created 288 different earth renders depending on sun position (one for every 5 earth minutes) based on [this](http://www.blendswap.com/blends/scenes/earth-we-are-alone/) file from blendswap. It the image sequence starts at noon and ends at noon. I would like to set at each time of day the correct image as background image on OS X (eg at 12.00 it should be image No 1 at 18:00 it should be image No 72 ). How could I do that.

(The Original Idea was to use the "change background image every 5 minutes" setting in OS X background settings, but it only changes the picture if the computer is awake. Therefore the sequence would be out of sync every time I shut down the computer

btw I uploaded the Files

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19023009/Blender/background.zip

They are at full Retina resolution at 650MB. + blendfile + license.

Comment: Can you please revise your question to clearly state the problem you are trying to solve? As it's written now, it doesn't really make sense.

Comment: yep you are right and there is even a error in my thought

Comment: You want a third party app suggestion which can do this or you want to write a script for this ?

Comment: I would rather write my on script, I found some third party apps myself already but I don't believe it would be to hard to do it myself. I already now how to change a background image with applescript (at least I believe) the interesting part is to execute it every 5 minutes according to system time

Comment: I think I am going to mix [this](http://superuser.com/questions/44849/user-friendly-way-to-schedule-jobs-in-mac-os-x) together with the automator action of changing the background

Comment: I would recommend to separate the scheduling from the picture selection to avoid the sleep issue. Just have a launchd job running a shell script every 5 minutes, the script can then figure out which image needs to be displayed.

Comment: yes my thoughts as well thanks. Do you know what the difference is between a Cron job and a launchd job? And how I add one. I am close to finishing the apple script to change the background. Soon I will need to figure out how I can run it on shedule. The good thing is, that it doesn't need to be exact because the image barely changes in 5 minute steps. And I would need it to run everytime I wake up/start the computer.

Comment: launchd handles wake up scenarios better than cron so I would definitively go with launchd. I don't know whether you can execute Applescripts from either one though.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for your input

So finally I managed to do it (at least I think so)

I embedded an Applescript to change the background in a shell script which I added it to launchd.

This is what it looks like:

Script "scriptly.sh"

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e '
set myhour to get the (hours of (current date))
set myminutes to get the (minutes of (current date))
set mypicturenumber to (myhour - 12) * 12 + myminutes / 5 as integer
if mypicturenumber < 0 then
    set mypicturenumber to (288 + mypicturenumber)
end if
set picnumber to 0
if mypicturenumber > 99 then
    set picnumber to "0" & mypicturenumber
end if

if (99 ≥ mypicturenumber) = (9 < mypicturenumber) then
    set picnumber to "00" & mypicturenumber
end if
if 9 ≥ mypicturenumber then
    set picnumber to "000" & mypicturenumber
end if
tell application "Finder"
    set desktop picture to {"Macintosh HD:users:USERNAME:Individualfile:backgrounds:earth:earth24h" & picnumber & ".png"} as alias
end tell
'
```

launchd file "com.individual.Background.plist"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.individual.Background</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/sh</string>
        <string>/Users/USERNAME/Individualfile/scriptly.sh</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>300</integer>
    <key>UserName</key>
    <string>USERNAME</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

command to put it in action

launchctl load /Users/USERNAME/Individualfile/com.individual.Background.plist

EDIT:

The last command is there to load the script directly, however It will not be executed on startup. To do That you have to copy the file

com.individual.Background.plist

to the ~/Libary/LaunchAgents/ folder.

Comment: The third condition in the script looks wrong. You could also run the AppleScript directly with something like `<string>osascript</string><string>/Users/username/script.scpt</string>`. The `UserName` key is not needed in per-user services saved to `~/Library/LaunchAgents/`.

Comment: Thanks for that, it told me in the console, that it the private key was not necessary and would be ignored, so I didn't change it. And the I wasn't sure if I could launch it directly with osascript, because osascript was throwing errors because of some permission to change user things when I ran it from the commandline

Answer (score 0):

This might be an unfortunate answer, but i'd suggest making a Quartz composition for this, turn it into a screen saver, and use one of many available tricks for running screen savers as a wall paper.

Comment: Good idea in general,I would need to look how I can make a time dependent screensaver.

Comment: Quartz Compositor probably has goodies in the library for tracking time (can't confirm right now)

Comment: Just finished the Applescript. I am going to add a launchd job to run the script every 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shorter version of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=$(((($(date +%H)-12)*12)+$(date +%M)/5))
[[ $n -lt 0 ]] && n=$((n+288))
n=$(printf %04d $n)

osascript -e "tell app \"Finder\" to set desktop picture to POSIX file \"/Users/username/Desktop/background/earth24h$n.png\""
```

You could run the script every five minutes by editing the crontab with `EDITOR=nano crontab -e` and adding a line like `*/5 * * * * ~/script.sh`. Unlike the LaunchAgent, it wouldn't be run after waking up from sleep though.

Comment: nice shell coding. I don't have that kind of skill level.